# Safari mobile ignoring media print styles

Tags: ios, css, printing, media-queries, mobile-safari

I have article page and print button on it, and if I try print this page, I see, that the margin of the page does not coincide with what I have indicated in the styles, images and text are cut in half (despite the page-break styles). On Android devices this is not observed.

I changed size of page to 'letter', I use page-break-before: auto;        page-break-after: auto;break-inside: avoid;display: block on images and on text (p, li, pre)

```css
@media print {
    @page {
        size: A4;
        margin:10mm;
    }

    img {
        page-break-before: auto;
        page-break-after: auto;
        -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid;
          page-break-inside: avoid;
               break-inside: avoid;
        display: block;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 480px) and (min-width: 320px) and (orientation: portrait) {
    @page { size: letter;}
}
```